# Adding Time intelligence mandates Time dimension to have entries?

Tags: sql, ssas, olap-cube, dimension

Currently i am working on a project where we are adding Time Intelligence calculations to the exiting cube. As a part of this effort, we are converting an existing dimension ( it contained dates) into a 'Time dimension', we have tagged on Date, weeks, Month, Quarter and Year to corresponding columns.

Next, i fire up the wizard and select all the desired calculations and end the wizard with a bunch of calculated measures for the time intelligence calculations. However, when i try to save and process i get the following error.

"**DefaultMember(Date,Time Interval Date Calculations) (1, 1) The level '[Current Date]' object was not found in the cube when the string, [Time Interval Date Calculations].[Current Date], was parsed.**"

Here are the things i checked,

1. The presence of the DSV column by the name and the expression of N'Current Date'
2. The Level in the date dimension by the given name, and the default member with the option 'Enter an MDX expression that specifies the default member' and the correct member being referenced ([Time Interval Date Calculations].[Current Date]

Any idea on what the cube is complaining about? Another thing i noticed is that this error doesnt pop up when the dimension Date has some values in it. Due to the nature of our product , we ship an empty cube (i.e. the date dimension has no data in it). Could this be the problem? If so how do i fix it without adding dummy data in the dimension?

Thanks
Srikanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the same on the MSFT forum. The answer was to remove the default. Why the wizard adds the default despite the hard-coded value in the DSV defination and the implications of not having a default is still unknown and i am waiting for an answer from MSFT. here is the link to the question

[**MSFT Link to the answer**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/10707391-afe7-483b-8455-fb88cc901e3d/adding-time-intelligence-mandates-time-dimension-to-have-entries?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

Thanks